# Quote issue in PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping

I have scrape data from Telugu site:

[image]

when i got "**Suriya’s ‘24’ in legal tangle**" this kind of string then that quote is not recognized by php function and it's converted in different character([Issue Link](http://prntscr.com/6sccni)).

Code:

```
//
include "simple_html_dom.php";
// Get news from telugu site
$url = "http://www.123telugu.com/category/mnews";

$html = file_get_html($url);
$divs = $html->find('div.leading');
$result = array();
$status = FALSE;
$i = 0;
foreach ($divs as $d) {
    $status = TRUE;
    $title = $d->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
    $result[$i]['Title'] = $title;
    $link = $d->find('a', 0)->href;
    $result[$i]['Link'] = $link;
    $title = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($title));  // code for title
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    // code for image
    $image = '';
    foreach ($html->find('div.post-content') as $im) {
        $image = $im->find('img', 0)->src; // code for  image
    }
    $image = trim(str_replace('//', '', $image));
    $result[$i]['Image'] = $image;
    // code for content
    $content = '';
    foreach ($html->find('div.post-content p') as $co) {
        $content.= $co->plaintext;   // code for content
    }
    $result[$i]['Content'] = $content;
    $i++;
}

echo json_encode(array('Status' => $status, 'Data' => $result));
```

Comment: and the question is?

Comment: Did you get my question?

Comment: It's an encoding issue. The input string is a multi-byte character string (probably UTF-8); it cannot be handled correctly by [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and the other regular PHP [functions for strings](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). You have to use the functions of the [`mb_string` extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) and make sure the HTML DOM library you use is able to handle UTF-8 (or other multi-byte character encodings) correctly. (I think it is the culprit in this case).

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars_decode() might be the function that you are looking for. Just run the final output from the **scraper** with this function. It should decode all the special HTML encoded characters.

Check out: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: i have already tried htmlspecialchars_decode () , it can decode normal single,double quote not this one.

Answer (score 0):

We have to add following code on top of the page. will solve the issue.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$string= iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii//TRANSLIT', $string);
```